# Eines vs ein in 'Eines der Probleme'

Tags: article, indefinite-pronoun

I have found the phrase 'Eines der Probleme'.The question is: why 'eines'?I would rather expect 'ein der Probleme', since it is an indefinite article in nominative case.
Example:

> Eines der Probleme ist, daß die Privatwirtschaft hier sehr schwach vertreten ist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not the indefinite article *ein*, *eine*, *ein* but [the indefinite pronoun *einer*, *eine*, *eines*](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-einer3.html?lang=en) that can substitute for a noun.

There are other similar pairs of pronouns where one of them can replace an adjective and the other a noun, such as *mein* and *meines*:

> Dein Auto ist grün. Meines ist blau.
> Kein Mensch hat ihn gesehen. Keiner hat ihn gesehen.

Comment: The link appears to no longer point to the topic and needs to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

I would say: because.

You can actually skip the genitive noun phrase "der Probleme" to get to the actual grammatical phenomenon. It is the rough equivalent of "one" as a single pronoun in English, like "I have seen one". Let me outline outline the declension pattern (in singular) of that pronoun:

```
[masc.] einer [nom.] einem [dat.] einen [acc.]  

[fem.] eine [nom.] einer [dat.] eine [acc.]

[neut.] eines [nom.] einem [dat.] eines [acc.]
```

Note first that there is no proper genitive case when the pronoun is used alone. If the pronoun is accompanied by a genitive phrase, say with an definite article, then you can use

```
[gen.] eines der [masc.] einer der [fem.] eines der [neut.]
```

Note second that the endings of "ein-" are precisely like you would usually do with the indefinite article except for the nominative case. The underlying cause for appending the suffix, from the perspective of economical use of language, is probably to strengthen the case marking.

Comment: There certainly is still a genitive: _Das ist immerhin die Lösung **eines** unserer vielen Probleme._

Comment: @chirlu: Thank you for pointing this out. I have edited my answer. But I think without the genitive phrase, like in *_Das ist immerhin die Lösung eines_, the pronoun is not used in that position.

Answer (score -1):

Es geht das Thema vielleicht um schwach und stark Deklination .
z.b.: 
stark: der gute Mann des guten Mannes dem guten Mann den guten Mann (hier ist das Adjektiv schwach dekliniert; steht es aber allein, dann stark):
guter Mann guten Mannes gutem Mann guten Mann
und "ein" übernimmt, wenn allein gesetzt, die stake Form; also ein Mann, aber: einer der Männer, und so ist es dann in allen drei Geschlechtrn und allen vier Fällen Sg und Pl.

Comment: Willkommen! Was Du schreibst, ist aber nicht der Grund. Die zweieinhalb Jahre alte akzeptierte Antwort hat das bereits erklärt.