# "Eine" oder "Einer der zentralen Szenen"?

Tags: grammatical-case, article

Als Einleitung zu einer Interpretation von Faust schrieb ich "Einer der zentralen Szenen ist die Szene 'Marthens Garten'."  Nun behaupten einige, dass "eine" korrekt wäre, aber - ohne es genau begründen zu können - glaube ich dies nicht.  Leider sind meine Kenntnisse der deutschen Grammatik zu gering als dass ich es sicher sagen oder danach suchen könnte.

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27806/eines-vs-ein-in-eines-der-probleme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das ist ein **partitiver Genitiv**.
Sie haben: [Kern(partitives Attribut)].

Wir können umschreiben mit "von" (Dativ): `Eine von den zentralen Szenen`.

"Eine" ist meiner Ansicht nach eine alleinstehende Kardinalzahl.
Die Flektion richtet sich also nach (ii) der Duden-Randnummer 449:

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+---------+
|    /      | Maskulinum | Femininum | Neutrum |
+-----------+------------+-----------+---------+
| Nominativ | er         | e         | s/es    |
| Akkusativ | en         | e         | s/es    |
| Dativ     | em         | er        | em      |
| Genitiv   | es         | er        | es      |
+-----------+------------+-----------+---------+
```

Wie Sie sehen, gehört zum Nominativ Femininum die Endung "-e".
Der Rest des Wortes ist lediglich ein Extra. Es hat keine Auswirkung auf die Endung. Der Genitiv ist hier ein Mittel, wie man den Teil von einem Ganzen ausdrücken kann.

Answer (score 5):

"Eine" ist natürlich richtig. "Einer" wäre richtig, wenn die Nominalphrase im Genitiv oder Dativ stünde, tut sie aber nicht.

Man kann es einfach daran erkennen, was passiert, wenn man das weggelassene Substantiv wieder einfügt: *Eine **Szene** der zentralen Szenen ist die Szene ...*

Im Dativ hingegen: *Bei einer der zentralen Szenen kann ich nur den Kopf schütteln.* Weil: *Bei einer **Szene** der zentralen Szenen kann ich nur den Kopf schütteln.*

Comment: Diese Erklärung war auch mein erster Gedanke, sie ist aber falsch, denn bei Neutrum wäre es „eines“, nicht „ein“.

Comment: @CarstenS Ich denke nicht, dass das meine Erklärung falsch macht. Das Demonstrativpronomen muss in genau dem Fall dekliniert werden, den die Nominalphrase auch hätte, wenn sie aus einem Artikel + Substantiv bestünde. Dass nicht alle Demonstrativpronomen genau so lauten wie die entsprechenden Artikel, ändert daran nichts.

Comment: Es gibt das Nominativpronomen _einer_, z.B. in "_Einer kam durch_". Es wird sowohl für Personen als auch für Sachen benutzt (Sache: _Die Plastik-Montierhebel taugen nix. Erst gestern ist mir wieder einer abgebrochen_). Auch in Ernests Frage handelt es sich um dieses Pronomen, allerdings wäre die Bezeichnung 'indefinites Pronomen' zutreffender. Da _Szene_ weiblich ist, muss es im Nominativ _eine der zentralen Szenen_ heißen. Übrigens stört die Wiederholung von 'Szene', eher so; _Eine der zentralen Szenen ist 'Marthens Garten'._

Comment: @RalfJoerres Richtig, es handelt sich hier keinesfalls um eine Auslassung des "echten" Nomens "Szene" - was die Antwort suggeriert -, "eine" erfüllt den Zweck bereits.
"Ein" als Indefinitpronomen richtet sich aber immer auf eine Person. Was Sie als Beispiel nehmen, nutzt "ein" als Kardinalzahl! Unter den Grammatikern ist umstritten, zu was die Kardinalzahlen gehören. Dementsprechend ist es eher eine Simplifikation, zu sagen, dieses "ein" wäre ein Pronomen. Allerdings wäre es richtig, von "pronominal" zu sprechen, das ist klar.